# What happens if I interrupt a database compression query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, compression

I'm altering a MySQL table to be compressed using the Barracuda file format, setting the key block size to 8, and the row format to compressed.

There are about 766 million records in this table. Or maybe it was just 76 million. Anyway, it's been processing for 32 hours so far, and I'm guessing when I check tomorrow it very well may still be going.

If I were to kill the process, what would happen? Would some records be compressed, but others not? Would the whole table be corrupted? Please advise.